# How can I do a loop in osmnx in order to calculate the basic stats for several municipalities?

Tags: python, osmnx

What it would be the best way to do a loop in osmnx in order to obtain the dataframe of each municipality and export them (individually) to a .csv file. So, my code is the following:

```
import osmnx as ox 
ox.config(log_console=True, use_cache=True)
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import geopandas as gpd
%matplotlib inline

locations = ['Barcelona, Spain', 'Madrid, Spain', "Seville, Spain"]
for location in locations:
    try:
        gdf = ox.geocode_to_gdf(location)
        area = ox.project_gdf(gdf).unary_union.area
        G = ox.graph_from_place(location, network_type="drive")

        stats = ox.basic_stats(G, area=area)
        for k, count in stats["streets_per_node_counts"].items():
            stats["{}way_int_count".format(k)] = count
        for k, proportion in stats["streets_per_node_proportions"].items():
            stats["{}way_int_prop".format(k)] = proportion
    
        del stats['streets_per_node_counts']
        del stats['streets_per_node_proportions']
        
        df = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(stats, name="value")).round(3)
        df.to_csv("/Users/hugocarpena/Desktop/df.csv")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

My problem is that when I export the .csv file I only get one with the stats of the three cities (jointly) and I want to get them individually - with every file named as the city. Any recommendations?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Do you want a separate csv file for each city's stats, rather than each city's stats appearing as a single row within one csv file?

Comment: Well, as you said, It might be better to create a single csv file where each city's stats appear as a single row.

Comment: Your csv file name is same for all cities first of all make that name dynamic not static

Comment: Yeah, I am aware of that, but before I would like to know if it is something wrong in the code.